# Location based iPhone app architecture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, core-location

I am in the process of building a location-based iPhone app and I am unsure of my architecture. I plan on using Core Resource (http://coreresource.org/) along with Core Data to manage the objects on a remote server. I then plan on sending the current location of the client to the server and querying for results within that geo-location. I am unaware of any alternatives to Core Resource or this architecture. Any tutorials or comments to point me in the correct direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [SimpleGeo's Storage API](https://simplegeo.com/products/storage/) for this. [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) also has a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've only recently started with CoreData (which is awesome), and have never heard of Core Resources, but it looks pretty neat. Right now though I'm using MagicalRecord https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord in a few of my projects. Also Cocoa Is My Girlfriend had some articles about Core Data not too long ago that I found useful http://www.cimgf.com/

Hope that helps.